# Unable to query for date using NSPredicate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to make a fetch for dates later than a specific date. My predicate is as follows:

```
NSPredicate(format: "date > \(currentDate)")
```

When I executed the fetch request I caught an exception:

```
'Unable to parse the format string "date > 2015-07-08 03:00:00 +0000"'
```

I thought I could make a query like that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`NSPredicate(format:_:)` takes a format string and a list of arguments, but you're passing a simple string. This doesn't work, since this initializer doesn't just call `stringWithFormat:` on the parameters, but actually looks at the arguments'  type information as it's building the predicate.

You can use that initializer by passing the date as an argument:

```
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", currentDate)
```

Comment: and `currentDate` should be of type Date, right? or can it be a string ?

Answer (score 75):

In swift 3 the predicate changed to:

```
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", currentDate as NSDate)
```

Comment: Didn't know that explicit casting to NSDate is mandatory when using NSPredicate on Swift. Thank you

Answer (score 31):

With Swift 3, according to your needs, you may choose one of 5 the following patterns in order to solve your problem.

---

#### #1. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(format:​arguments:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1417368-init) initializer with `NSDate` instance

`NSPredicate` has an initializer called `init(format:​arguments:​)` that has the following declaration:

```
init(format predicateFormat: String, arguments argList: CVaListPointer)
```

> Creates and returns a new predicate by substituting the values in an argument list into a format string and parsing the result.

When used with `NSDate`, you can set an instance of `NSPredicate` by using `init(format:​arguments:​)` as indicated below:

```
let date = NSDate()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", date)
```

---

#### #2. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(format:argumentArray:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1410334-init) initializer with `NSDate` instance

`NSPredicate` has an initializer called `init(format:argumentArray:)` that has the following declaration:

```
init(format predicateFormat: String, argumentArray arguments: [Any]?)
```

> Creates and returns a new predicate by substituting the values in a given array into a format string and parsing the result.

When used with `NSDate`, you can set an instance of `NSPredicate` by using `init(format:​argumentArray:​)` as indicated below:

```
let date = NSDate()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", argumentArray: [date])
```

---

#### #3. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(format:​arguments:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1410334-init) initializer with `Date` instance casted to `NSDate`

When used with `Date`, you can set an instance of `NSPredicate` by casting your `Date` instance to `NSDate` as indicated below:

```
let date = Date()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", date as NSDate)
```

---

#### #4. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(format:​arguments:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1410334-init) initializer with `Date` instance casted to `CVarArg`

When used with `Date`, you can set an instance of `NSPredicate` by casting your `Date` instance to `CVarArg` as indicated below:

```
let date = Date()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", date as CVarArg)
```

---

#### #5. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(format:argumentArray:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1410334-init) initializer with `Date` instance

When used with `Date`, you can set an instance of `NSPredicate` by using `init(format:argumentArray:)` as indicated below:

```
let date = Date()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", argumentArray: [date])
```